# Как инициализировать ЛЮБОЙ плагин после его динамического добавления через AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, select2, slick.js

После динамического добавления любого плагина через AJAX (будь то select2 или slick) их нужно инициализировать. Я перепробовал уже всё что можно, ничего не работает, даже этот метод

```
$('.content').load("BlogPost.php .content", function () {
            $(selector).select2(); 

        });
```

*Также пробовал делать функцию обёртку для инициализации а потом передавать в неё тот самый динамический селектор плагина, и всё это тоже не работает.*
Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста реально **ДЕЙСТВЕННЫЙ** метод который может инициализировать плагины.
И вообще очень странно что нет никаких специальных методов для динамически созданных плагинов наподобие on() для стандартных обработчиков. 
Заранее благодарю
P.S. Все методы описанные в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625993/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-jquery-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-ajax-%D0%BE) вопросе не работают для моей ситуации т.к селектор плагина проходит через динамический контейнер. Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь способы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как использовать плагины jquery с динамическим контентом или почему после AJAX отваливается javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625993/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-jquery-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-ajax-%d0%be)

Comment: Смотрел этот вопрос. Испробовал все методы. Ничего не работает. 
@Grundy В том вопросе есть одна интересная строка: "Способ выше не будет работать если используемый для плагина селектор проходит через динамический контейнер". Так вот в моём случае селектор как раз таки проходит через контейнер. Я поэтому и спрашиваю, есть ли ещё какие-нибудь методы инициализации?

Comment: _Способ выше не будет работать если используемый для плагина селектор проходит через динамический контейнер_, читай дальше: _В таком случае вам, наверное, стоит более внимательно отнестись к тому что и как вы обновляете или загружаете вместо слепого применения трюка с applyPlugins._ На самом деле все работает, просто ты неверно выбираешь на чем инициализировать

Comment: @Grundy Подскажи пожалуйста как тогда правильно инициализировать, потом что я уже сломал голову)
Или может быть стоит по другому подгружать плагины? У меня подгружается обёртка плагина вместе с основным контентом, не данные для этого плагина, а сам плагин

Comment: Для этого нужно видеть минимальный пример, которые воспроизводит именно твою ошибку. Потому что в общем случае решение простое: в месте, где ты вставляешь что-то в разметку, после вставки нужно выбрать нужный элемент и инициализировать плагин.

Comment: @Grundy Только что удалось инициализировать плагин select2. А вот плагин slick никак не хочет инициализироваться. Я уже создавал вопрос по плагину slick, но ответа не нашёл к сожалению [тот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712031/ajax-%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-slick-%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/712048#712048). Там проблема расписана более подробно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64883/discussion-between-grundy-and-smegol).